How do I restore the 3 or 4 lines to my .bashrc for working with Sdkman?
I've been happily using SDKMAN for quite some time.  The installation adds 3 or 4 lines to your .bashrc, which are identified as being necessarily the last lines of the file.
I corrupted my .bashrc (and backup failed) and do not know which lines to restore to my .bashrc.  Because those lines are missing, I cannot even invoke sdk.
I've searched the ~/.sdkman directory and found only one script in the bin directory: sdk-init.sh (which is not marked executable) and a slew of scripts in the scripts directory.  Like all the others, they are not marked executable.
I've also tried updating with the 'force' option.  It discovers that I already have it installed (where??!) and aborts execution... before (or without) validating the lines in .bashrc.  The system is Ubuntu 23.04, but this shouldn't be an issue.

Having bounced off the walls trying to recover my sdkman installation, a simple solution came to mind.  I created a new user and did a fresh install. Then I moved the last 3 lines from the new user's .bashrc and appended them to .bashrc of the original user.
The last 2 lines of ~/.bashrc are:
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
